# How can I classify the factors in the list using a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

There is a list named lists and a dictionary labeled categories.

```
lists = ["Ferrari", "Rose", "Samsung", "Porsche"]
categories = {"car": {"Ferrari", "Porsche"}, "flower": {"Rose", "Chamomile"}, "phone": {"Apple", "Samsung"}}
```

I would like to get a dictionary return with the names given in the list as key and the classification of the names as value.

like this.

```
{"Ferrari": "car", "Rose": "flower", "Samsung": "phone", "Porsche": "car"}
```

and this is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
def classify(lists: list, categories: dict):
result = {}

for i in range(len(lists)):
    if lists== categories.keys():
        result[lists] = categories.keys()

return result
```

Comment: Did you mean `result[lists[i]] = categories[lists[i]]`? if so remove the `if` statement

Comment: Actually no the code would still make 0 sense

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, using two `for` loops, I just did small changes to your existing **classify** function.

**Note:** In your existing code, when you iterate using a single `for` loop and comparing `lists==categories.keys()` then it is doing like this `['Ferrari', 'Rose', 'Samsung', 'Porsche'] == dict_keys(['car', 'flower', 'phone'])` which is wrong that's why it will not work as you required.

```
lists = ["Ferrari", "Rose", "Samsung", "Porsche"]
categories = {"car": {"Ferrari", "Porsche"}, "flower": {"Rose", "Chamomile"}, "phone": {"Apple", "Samsung"}}

def classify(lists: list, categories: dict):
    result = {}
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        for k, v in categories.items():
            if lists[i] in v:
                result[lists[i]] = k
    return result

print(classify(lists, categories))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Ferrari': 'car', 'Rose': 'flower', 'Samsung': 'phone', 'Porsche': 'car'}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this efficiently, you can create a reverse mapping that maps items to respective categories, so that you can create the new dict by iterating over the list and mapping each item to its category with the aforementioned mapping:

```
mapping = {item: category for category, items in categories.items() for item in items}
result = {item: mapping[item] for item in lists}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/SeashellHatefulWorkers

Comment: #Note : For the case if car name is `Lotus` and flower name is also `Lotus` then this reverse mapping will fail. Also OP needs to clarify on this what will happen in this case.

Comment: It's clear from the data structure of the expected output that the OP does not expect duplicating names under different categories to happen.

Comment: Then OP should construct dictionary correctly using values intead of keys if it is known to him that values will always be unique.

Comment: It is rather apparent that the OP does not have the permission to construct the input dict with a better data structure, or else the OP would not have asked this question to convert it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

More efficiently you can use the below approach

```
lists = ["Ferrari", "Rose", "Samsung", "Porsche"]
categories = {"car": {"Ferrari", "Porsche"}, "flower": {"Rose", "Chamomile"}, "phone": {"Apple", "Samsung"}}
new_dict = dict.fromkeys(lists, "")
for k,v in categories.items():
    t = dict.fromkeys(v, k)
    new_dict.update(t)
print({k: new_dict.get(k, "") for k in lists})
```

Comment: #Note : For the case if car name is `Lotus` and flower name is also `Lotus` then this reverse mapping will fail. Also OP needs to clarify on this what will happen in this case.